# I am getting missing helper error when I try to use handlebars.js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I included Handlebar.js in my hbs view as follow

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
      <script>       
        Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function (a, b, options) {
          if (a == b) { return options.fn(this); }
          return options.inverse(this);
        });

        Handlebars.registerHelper('ifnoteq', function (a, b, options) {
          if (a != b) { return options.fn(this); }
          return options.inverse(this);
        });
      </script>
```

But when I use it as follows I get an error "Missing helper: "ifeq"". What am I doing wrong?

```
{{#ifeq status "0"}}                           
    Status is : 0                     
{{/ifeq}}
```

Comment: I think there may be some confusion over what is executed on the server and what on the client. If you have hbs view files, then you are executing Handlebars on the server. So there is no need to include the Handlebars library client-side with the <script> tag. Your helpers will need to be registered server-side.

Comment: Then how to do it on the server side?

Comment: The documentation for whichever Handlebars view engine you are using will tell you what you need to do. For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs#helpers-and-partials

Answer (score 0):

Here's a runnable example showing it working on the client:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("ifeq", function (a, b, options) {
  if (a == b) { return options.fn(this); }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
const html = document.querySelector("#template").innerHTML;
const template = Handlebars.compile(html);
document.body.innerHTML = template({status: "0"});
```

```html
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#ifeq status "0"}}
    Status is : 0
{{/ifeq}}
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@4.7.8/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
```

If you really want to handle this templating on the server, move all of the code there instead of using `<script>` tags, which run later, on the client. For example:

```js
const express = require("express"); // ^14.18.2
const Handlebars = require("handlebars"); // ^4.7.8

const html = `
{{#ifeq status "0"}}
    Status is : 0
{{/ifeq}}`;

Handlebars.registerHelper("ifeq", function (a, b, options) {
  if (a == b) { return options.fn(this); }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
const template = Handlebars.compile(html);

const app = express();
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3001)
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(template({status: "0"}));
});
app.listen(
  app.get("port"),
  () => console.log(`running on ${app.get("port")}`)
);
```

Run this with `node index.js` and navigate to http://localhost:3001 to see the compiled template with the helper.

You may want to use Handlebars middleware if you want to scale up this minimal example.